# Identify devices on my network

Tags: wireless-networking

I keep getting these devices logging on to my network that are not mine or anyone else’s in my house. At first it was different random unknown devices that were on and off, they changed every time I paused one. But most recently it’s the same two and even after changing my network name & password they got on and again after changing it and hiding it one of them is already back on. One night a car drove by slowly and they were using a flash light looking at houses and ten minutes later I get two notifications that these devices have signed on for the first time, ever since that night (2:15am) I can’t get rid of them for longer than two weeks. I get notifications on my phone saying “nfc tag detected, sign on to cash app”, my phone has been hacked and XFINITY confirmed and told me to get rid of it immediately and redo the network again. Can anyone tell me what these devices are with the MAC address and bit of description there is for them?

```
android-462c57dacc3e01c7 
IPv4 Address
10.0.0.150
MAC Address
AC:DO:74:31:D0:3F
Comments
Reserved
```

```
wlan0
IPv4 Address
10.0.0.252
MAC Address
50:8A:06:AB:60:8B
Comments
DHCP
```

This is all the info I have, no one in my house has an android so it’s definitely not one ours…

Comment: This is mainly for mac/iPhone users, but shows some of the things you need to test/check/change if you suspect someone unauthorised can get inside your network - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437760/how-do-i-prevent-remote-access-to-my-mac

Comment: If you're using WPA2 or higher with AES (non-TKIP) and you changed the WiFi passphrase to a complex one, it's highly unlikely these are unauthorized devices - Android and iOS will both default to randomizing the MAC address of the device when they're being configured to connect to the WiFi network and it's recommended to disable this for your home LAN within the device's settings for your home LAN WiFi network. You can view all devices on your LAN via `arp -a`

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me what these devices are with the MAC address

No, the MAC address doesn't contain such precise information. About the only thing you can guess is what company made the device – or more commonly, what company made the "Wi-Fi radio" part of the device.

According to IEEE's OUI database, the MAC address *prefix* `AC:D0:74` belongs to "Espressif Inc.", and the prefix `50:8A:06` was issued to "Tuya Smart Inc.", both of which are IoT device man­u­fac­tur­ers (the former makes a very popular ESP32 microcontroller chip that's found in all kinds of 'smart' devices).

> no one in my house has an android so it’s definitely not one ours

It could be your smart TV/toaster/fridge/oven running Android for its user interface.

Comment: I don’t have any smart devices that haven’t been identified already

Comment: So am I crazy to think that someone has put a device on my house that they can access remotely and that device can connect via Bluetooth to mine?  I have an ex that was here at the start of all the new device signing on drama and I also have an ex-friend that stayed here and had notes on hacking and she’s destroying her parents credit by using it to rent places and not pay, buy things like vehicles and not paying and applying for credit everywhere!  I fear she’s doing it all as if it’s me doing it from my phone so she can get away with it.. She had my phone one day I think it’s cloned..crazy